# How to rename and save Unzip file in php

Tags: php, php-7, laravel-5.4

I am trying to unzip an uploaded file and rename and upload it in my server

here is my code

**PHP**

```
$fname = md5(rand()).'.csv';
                $full_path = Config::get('filesystems.disks.local.root');


                $zip = new ZipArchive;     

                if ($zip->open($excel_file) === TRUE) 
                {

                        $zip->renameName($zip->getNameIndex(0),$fname);
                        $zip->extractTo($full_path. '/exceluploads/');
                        $zip->close();
                } else {

                        return redirect()->back()->withErrors('File is not zipped');
                }
```

But this is not working , I am sure I am doing some mistake since I am using the `ZipArchive` for the first time .

Comment: Did you get any php error or warnings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are changing the zip file's content, so you need to specify what you want to extract.

```
<?php
$fname = md5(rand()).'.csv';
$full_path = Config::get('filesystems.disks.local.root');

$zip = new ZipArchive;

if ($zip->open($excel_file) === TRUE) {
    $zip->renameName($zip->getNameIndex(0), $fname);
    // Please notice the $fname, passed as a parameter for extractTo
    $zip->extractTo($full_path . 'exceluploads/', $fname);
    $zip->close();
} else {
    return redirect()->back()->withErrors('File is not zipped');
}
```